# Fragmented MP4 file playback in web browser

Tags: html, ffmpeg, html5-video

I want to build a MP4 streaming server.
I generated MP4 file with ffmpeg as follow.

```
$ffmpeg -i input.avi -movflags frag_keyframe output.mp4
```

It works normally in Google Chrome but IE9 and Safari just play a short period.
(One keyframe duration)
What is the proglem?

Thanks

The HTML code is here:

```
<body>
  <video id="myvideo" controls="controls">
    <source src="output.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
       The browser does not support HTML5
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```